# How to reset all Facebook Permission in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, permissions

i'm developing an application for iOS and for test app, i need clear/reset all facebook permission... how can do this?

if check the permission whit graph path, i see this log

```
[PF_FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions"
                         completionHandler:^(PF_FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                             NSLog(@"facebook_permission: %@",result);


                         }];
```

the result is

```
[6412:c07] facebook_permission: {
data =     (
            {
        "create_note" = 1;
        email = 1;
        installed = 1;
        "photo_upload" = 1;
        "publish_actions" = 1;
        "publish_stream" = 1;
        "share_item" = 1;
        "status_update" = 1;
        "user_about_me" = 1;
        "user_birthday" = 1;
        "user_location" = 1;
        "video_upload" = 1;
    }
);
```

i want to clear all permission.. it's possible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. Here is an example.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"
                     parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"delete"
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result,    NSError *error)                                                                               {
                      if (!error && result == true) {
                        // Revoking the permission worked
                        NSLog(@"Permission successfully revoked");
                      } else {
                        // There was an error, handle it
                        NSLog(@"here was an error");
                        // See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
                      }
}];
```

For example,if you want to delete an specific permissions just change the path, here i'm revoking the publish__actions permissions `startWithgraphPath:@"/me/permissions/publish_actions"`

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference) , is the list with the permission.